# Google Drive API - Get a file's metadata: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am using google api php client to use the drive in my company.

But I have a problem:
When get in the drive a file's metadata by ID, the code generates error.

`{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } }`

#### Code example

```php
<?php

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

$client = new Client();
$client->setAuthConfig([
      'type' => 'service_account',
      'client_id' =>'xxxxxx',
      'client_email' => 'xxxxxx',
      'private_key_id' => 'xxxxxx',
      'private_key' => 'xxxxxx',
]);
$client->setScopes([
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]);
$client->setSubject('xxxxxx');
$drive = new Drive($client);

$fileId = 'xxxxxx';

$optParams = [
      'fields' => '*',
];

$results = $drive->files->get($fileId, $optParams); // -> error 403
```

Note: It's the same problem for the other methods of the api drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a Project in the Google Cloud platform and performed Domain wide delegation in the Google Workspace?

Comment: @CizRanger Yes, I already have existing code that uses the Gmail service and groups and I have no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had another code that rewrote the scopes right after.

So I replaced in all my code `setScopes()` with `addScope()`.